# gsoap: force WS-Discovery 1.0 instead of 1.1

Tags: gsoap, ws-discovery

I am using gsoap and its plugin wsddapi to implement WS-Discovery.

I need to implement WS-Discovery v1.0, but the plugin output only v1.1 messages. In the source-code of the plugin, they say it's valid both for v1.1 and v1.0, but I am not able to understand how I can force gsoap to use v1.0 messages.

Do you have any hint?

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate soapClient.cpp code that is referenced by wsddapi plugins for WS-Discovery 1.0, you can use a command like :

```
 soapcpp2 -xa /usr/share/gsoap/WS/wsdd10.h -I /usr/share/gsoap/import
```

In the other hand code for WS-Discovery 1.1 could be generated with :

```
 soapcpp2 -xa /usr/share/gsoap/WS/wsdd.h -I /usr/share/gsoap/import
```

Perhaps your paths are different depending on packaging, operating system ...